# Is there a way to move multiple non-Copy elements out of an array?

Tags: rust

Is there any way to deconstruct the array like `[a, b] = map` so the two array elements are moved into `a` and `b`, so that later `a` and `b` can be moved into another function (like `printme` in this case).

```
enum Direction {
    North,
    East,
    South,
    West,
}

struct RoadPoint {
    direction: Direction,
    index: i32,
}

fn printme(a: RoadPoint, b: RoadPoint) {
    println!("First: {}", a.index);
}

fn main() {
    let mut map: [RoadPoint; 2] = [
        RoadPoint {
            direction: Direction::North,
            index: 0,
        },
        RoadPoint {
            direction: Direction::North,
            index: 0,
        },
    ];

    for i in 1..3 {
        map[i].index = 10;
    }

    //move out
    printme(map[0], map[1])
}
```

```
error[E0508]: cannot move out of type `[RoadPoint; 2]`, a non-copy array
  --> src/main.rs:34:13
   |
34 |     printme(map[0], map[1])
   |             ^^^^^^ cannot move out of here

error[E0508]: cannot move out of type `[RoadPoint; 2]`, a non-copy array
  --> src/main.rs:34:21
   |
34 |     printme(map[0], map[1])
   |                     ^^^^^^ cannot move out of here
```

I'm aware of the fact I could implement the `Copy` trait, but I actually don't need copy of data in this case. Hence I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Some of your code is not very idiomatic: prefer direct iteration over collections instead of index ranges (`for point in &mut map { }`).

Answer (score 2):

You can get it to work if you use nightly Rust with the *non-lexical lifetimes* feature and a fixed-length slice pattern:

```
#![feature(nll)]

enum Direction {
    North,
    East,
    South,
    West,
}

struct RoadPoint {
    direction: Direction,
    index: i32,
}

fn printme(a: RoadPoint, b: RoadPoint) {
    println!("First: {}", a.index);
    println!("Second: {}", b.index);
}

fn main() {
    let map: [RoadPoint; 2] = [
        RoadPoint {
            direction: Direction::North,
            index: 0,
        },
        RoadPoint {
            direction: Direction::North,
            index: 0,
        },
    ];

    let [a, b] = map;
    printme(a, b);
}
```

Without `#![feature(nll)]` it fails with:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `map[..]`
  --> src/main.rs:30:13
   |
30 |     let [a, b] = map;
   |          -  ^ value used here after move
   |          |
   |          value moved here
   |
   = note: move occurs because `map[..]` has type `RoadPoint`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Comment: thanks a lot. that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there also a workaround for non-nightly versions?
Could I recast the pointer in usafe mode ?

Comment: Arrays of non `Copy` types in Rust are not very flexible. Maybe you can do something like `let mut v : Vec<_> = (Box::new(map) as Box<[_]>).into(); let b = v.pop().unwrap(); let a = v.pop().unwrap();`. But if you are into that, then you could use a `Vec` instead of an array in the first place!

Comment: thanks a ton!

yeah, I might go for a Vec and pop().
This means the data is stored on the heap. Are there any performance implications due to this?

Comment: For a stable version, you may look at [split_at](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at)

Comment: @hellow: But `split_at` applies to slices, not to arrays, that is, they return borrowed references. The OP asks for a way to move values out of the array.

Comment: @Stefan: Sure, there are performance issues. It depends on the length of the array, the size of the stored objects, the usage patterns... if you really care about that you should profile your program. Beware of premature optimizations!

Comment: I suggest moving your good answer to the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Done, thanks for the tip. I copied both the _fixed length slice pattern_ and the _boxing array_ solutions.